# Загнутые уголки HTML+CSS

Tags: html, css

**Здравствуйте!**

Как можно визуально "загнуть" уголок блока HTML страницы так, чтобы это не зависело от бэкграунда блока? Не встречалась ли вам такая задача?

Answer (score 2):

[Тут](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=2&id=895) урок исключительно по ним.

Comment: Читал уже - не помогло. Зависит от цвета блока...

Comment: Может быть это поможет:
http://www.rusdigi.org/css3/sozdaem-krasivuyu-ikonku-s-pomoshhyu-css3.html

Comment: Выглядит классно!

Comment: Спасибо за урок

Answer (score 1):

Советую еще почитать эту статью [Как сделать загнутые уголки на CSS3 без картинок](http://htmlbook.ru/blog/kak-sdelat-zagnutye-ugolki-na-css3-bez-kartinok) и оригинал тут - [How to Create CSS3 Paper Curls Without Images](http://www.sitepoint.com/pure-css3-paper-curl/).

Comment: Это не совсем то, но статья полезная. Плюсану, пожалуй.